# AND Relationship not working in Search and Filter Pro's custom search using WP Query

Tags: wordpress

I am using Search and Filter Pro plugin to fetch search result based on various post meta and taxonomies, I am not completely using the plugin's entire interface only its custom query approach:

https://searchandfilter.com/documentation/search-results/custom/

I attached search and filter to the `WP_Query` and that part looks like this:

```
$premium_args = array(
                "s" => $_GET['q'],
                'posts_per_page' => 20, 
                'paged' => 1, 
                'post_type' => array( 'contactdirectory'),
                'orderby' => 'title',
                'order'   => 'ASC',
);  

$premium_args['search_filter_id'] = 166;
```

And in the plugin I have set the 'Field relationships:' to `AND` for that search and filter instance.

However it's not working as expected, here's an example:

https://indiadairy.com/?s=&p_type=cd&_sft_Industries=equipment-manufacturers&_sfm_state=Maharashtra

`_sft_Industries=equipment-manufacturers` is there, and then `_sfm_state=Maharashtra` but in the search results you can see there are results which has a different value for `Industries` taxonomy like `Dairy Plants` and 'NGO' whereas it should only return results that satisfies the value passed to both parameters.

I tried adding

```
'meta_query' => array(
   'relation' => 'AND',
)
```

It doesn't work, which I expected, as it's for meta queries passed manually in the `WP_Query` arguments.

Comment: How did you solve this? I have the same problem.. :/

Comment: @asored sorry, I do not remember what the problem was, I will get back to you after checking my code and see if I can recall.